# Alternatives for SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery or SQL jobs? (for calling a stored procedure asynchronously from asp.net web page)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sqlcommand, sql-job

**Aim:** Calling a very slow stored procedure (with parameters) asynchronously from code behind of an asp.net web page via single function call, and then forgetting about it.

**Notes:** I tried using `SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery` without calling `SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery` (see the code below), but the stored procedure didn't run. (I used a tiny stored procedure to update single field on a table for testing but the field was not updated. It gets update when I use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`).

I am not interested in and don't know when the stored procedure will end. (So I can't wait for it to finish to call `SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQuery`.)

**Situation:**
After some research, I found out that sql jobs can be used for this purpose. And for the sp parameters; I can store them in a table and then sp can read them. However I don't know if this is the right approach to my problem (I am new to SQL world). I hope you can comment on usage of an sql job for this purpose, or suggest alternatives. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
        @"Data Source=XXX\MSSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=YYY;Integrated Security=True"
        + ";Asynchronous Processing=true"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTestProcedure", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pText", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(); //Doesn't work.
        //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // This works.
    }
```

Comment: Nope, I have to use asp.net 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a way of doing this from the code behind of asp.net, but realized there is no easy way of doing it (I didn't want to think about connection or time out problems). I ended up doing it via a web service.

1. From asp.net code behind, I call my webs service's function synchronously.
2. Within the web service's function, I call the stored procedure *asynchronously* using `SqlCommand.BeginexecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallback, Object)`.
3. The callback is handled within the web service (for error handling).

Hence my web page keeps working the way I want: Fire the request once, then forget about it.

Comment: can you explain more? this is my problem today i want to execute a specific stored procedure and forget about it, can you show me some sample codes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply execute your sp in a separate thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Would this be affected from the time out of the ASP page? Also, if the client gets disconnected (e.g. network connection drops), would the stored procedure keep running till it finishes its job?

Comment: To be honest I am not 100% sure. My best guess is it will continue processing once it is fired. Easily tested, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use ThreadPool for example to make a sync call on a separate thread.

It will looks something like this...

**Extract method:**

```
private void ExecuteCommandSync()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( 
        @"Data Source=XXX\MSSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=YYY;Integrated Security=True" 
        + ";Asynchronous Processing=true")) 
    { 
        connection.Open(); 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTestProcedure", connection); 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pText", DateTime.Now.ToString())); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
```

**Change your code:**

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) => { ExecuteCommandSync(); });
```

It will make a synchronous call on some thread from ThreadPool, once it is done - it will close connection and you are done.
It is not the BEST solution performance-wise, because you will have a thread sleeping while it waits for the Stored Proc, but it is good enough and will do what you want.

Comment: For SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, if the client gets disconnected (e.g. network connection drops), would the stored procedure keep running till it finishes its job?